# If you try to pour water into a coiled hose as shown, no water will come out of the other end. Why ? (You should not connect it to a tap)

Tags: fluid-statics

If you try to pour water into a coiled hose as shown, no water will come out of the other end. Why ? (You should not connect it to a tap).  [J.Walker]
[image]

Comment: Welcome To Physics SE. What do you mean by "not connect to a tap"?

Comment: Water does come out of a coiled hose.